# Is there any work around for "Can't open Bazel-real : Bad CPU type in executable"

Tags: bazel

I use MacBook Pro, BigSur OS. I am trying to build Bazel. But I always get "Can't open Bazel-real : Bad CPU type in executable" error. I have been downloaded using curl as well as from binary installer but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried using `brew` ?

install `brew`

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

then install `bazel`

```
brew install bazel
```

check if its properly installed

```
bazel --version
```

Comment: glad to be of help